# Set alarm for custom metrics of EC2s in the same Auto Scaling Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk, aws-auto-scaling

Normally I can set the alarm for autoscaling group , because it returns the memoy utilization or CPU utilization for each autoscalinggroup(or task difinition) as default.

It is easy to make alarm, because `CPU` or `memory` usage is bundled together for each auto scaling group

However I want to get the `GPU` Usage, so I installed the `gpumon.py` in EC2 of autoscaling group and get the custom metorics for GPU Usage.

But it this metrics is devided by instance id even in the same auto scaling group.

Is it possible to make alarm with bundling these metrics?

[image]

Comment: What is gpumon.py? Maybe you can add a AutoScalingGroup dimension to your custom metric. Then you can query the metric for the AutoScalingGroup dimension instead of the InstanceId dimension.

Comment: Thank you I restart learning the dimension of cloudwatch and found the way to use query builder. I can solve the my progrem.